# MVC: Dynamic routes in Home-Controller without affecting other controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, routes

This is no general question about how controllers and actions work, but a question about presenting known url structures to the user in a dotnet core MVC Client.

I want to build a "home page" with a blog and maybe later with a shop. The general Url structure should be

```
https://xxx.xx/... => Homepage content
https://xxx.xx/Blog/... => Blog content
https://xxx.xx/Shop/... => Shop content
```

"Blog" and "Shop" are specific areas within the website, so the extra path is familiar for a user and controllers and actions work as intended.

For the home page normally you have a structure something like that:

```
https://xxx.xx/ => Index
https://xxx.xx/privacy
https://xxx.xx/about
https://xxx.xx/company/team
```

What you do not want (for the eye) is something like

```
https://xxx.xx/Home/privacy
```

In addition I like to get these "pages" from a database, so that the Home controller itself has two conditions:

1. If nothing comes after the domain, call the Home controller, Index action and Index.cshtml
2. If there is something following the domain which has not the path "Blog/" or "Shop/", it is a name or slug of a page and therefore call the Home controller with a "page action" and display Page.cshtml with content from the database.

If I do something like this in the Home controller

```
[HttpGet("{slug?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string slug)
```

the kind I like the home page to work works, but I can not call any other controllers anymore.

I played around with custom routes but my problem is that obviously the routing can not distinguish between "path" and "action.

Is there a solution to my problem or is this something I have to deal with?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Route and redirect it to target

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Link",
                url: "{slug}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Slug", action = "GoTo" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

and in slug Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GoTo(string ShortLink)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ShortLink))
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


            LinkModels linkModels = db.Links.Where(sl => sl.ShortLinkURL == ShortLink).FirstOrDefault();

            if (linkModels == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ClickModels cm = new ClickModels();
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                {
                    linkModels.ReferralCount++;
                    cm.LinkType = 1;
                    cm.RequestURL = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
                    cm.RequestIP = BitOneWeb.Helper.GetClientIP.GetIP();
                    cm.ClickDateTime = DateTime.Now;


                }
                else
                {
                    linkModels.DirectCount++;
                    cm.LinkType = 0;
                    //cm.RequestURL = "Direct";
                    cm.RequestIP = BitOneWeb.Helper.GetClientIP.GetIP();
                    cm.ClickDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                }
                linkModels.LinkCount = linkModels.DirectCount + linkModels.ReferralCount;
                db.Clicks.Add(cm);
                linkModels.Clicks.Add(cm);

                db.Entry(linkModels).State = EntityState.Modified;


                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Redirect(linkModels.LongLinkURL);
            }
        }
```

This is work fine for me, But if you have fix controller like `http://yoursite/blog` or `http://yoursite/contact` you can static handle that in slug controller

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I added the "Link" route in my startup.cs under app.UseMvc(routes... What do you mean with "redirect it to target"? If I have https://mywebsite.com/about and "about" is the slug and I am in the GoTo-Action in the Slug-Controller, where do I need to redirect to?

Comment: You should store slug in database or in your route if it not find go to another route, I used it for shortlink engine and work fine

Comment: That's exactly what I plan to do, but besides "slugs" I have normal Controllers and Actions too. But for the router there is no difference between https://website.com/slug and https://website.com/Blog which is the Blog-Controller and the Index-Action.

Comment: See my code, It's working fine you can handle static to direct to the controller that fix in your app